# Why did i get old value after scan wifi to get ssid and level

Tags: java, android, android-wifi

I want to get WiFi scan results to plot graphs. What should I do? My problem is the new and previous values are present in the `JSONArray`. I hope to get only the the new value.

```
class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

        for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
            List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = null;
            wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
            for (ScanResult config : wifiScanList) {
                try {
                    jsonObject.put("ssid", config.SSID);
                    jsonObject.put("rssi", config.level);
                    jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            try {
                mainObj.put("data"+j, jsonArray);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d("pj492", String.format(" * %d %s", j, mainObj));
            wifiScanList.clear();
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                //Handle exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But results is...

> 0
>   {"data0":[{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83},{"ssid":"@TOT_Wi-Fi","rssi":-83}]}...

Comment: What are `jsonObject` and `jsonArray`? Shouldn't they be scoped inside your method?

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. What is your problem exactly? Which result are you expecting? Not that your code is not compilable, declarations are missing. See [ask].

Comment: I keep to JSON for send to web service. Its easy. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just want to prevent multiple SSID values to be added to `jsonArray`.
You can do this by keeping track of previously added SSID values, and only add new values that are encountered.

Just use an extra `ArrayList` to keep track of SSID values that have already been added:

```
 class WifiScanReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        ArrayList<String> ssidList = new ArrayList<String>(); //store previously encountered SSID values

        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {

            for (int j=0; j<10; j++) {
                List<ScanResult> wifiScanList = null;
                wifiScanList = mainWifiObj.getScanResults();
                for (ScanResult config : wifiScanList) {
                    //only add SSID to jsonArray if it has not been added already
                    if (!ssidList.contains(config.SSID)) {
                        try {
                            jsonObject.put("ssid", config.SSID);
                            jsonObject.put("rssi", config.level);
                            jsonArray.put(jsonObject);
                            ssidList.add(config.SSID); //add current SSID to the list to prevent duplicate entries
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                try {
                    mainObj.put("data"+j, jsonArray);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Log.d("pj492", String.format(" * %d %s", j, mainObj));
                wifiScanList.clear();
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //Handle exception
                }
            }
        }
    }
```